# whats the difference between stratus and flash media server 4

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-media-server, soundcloud-stratus

I want to create a simple video chat application using rtmfp the new p2p feature. It's available in flash media server 4 and using stratus, I've only been able to find tutorials on stratus. So my question is if I want to use the p2p feature in flash media server 4 do I have to signup for stratus and use its api or does fms 4 have its own api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your goal? If you need to make just a videochat, you can use FMS only, without stratus. Just connect to server, perform connection accept on serverside, and then you can use `publish` and `play` methods of `NetStream` class. But if you want to perform videochat through p2p, than you do not need FMS (because the main idea of p2p - communication without server), but still you can use FMS for managing clients, and perform video streaming through stratus.

Comment: does netstream use p2p on fms? or will the data be transferred to server then the user? Is it possible to do p2p video chat through only fms?

Comment: I'm a bit confused about it, I don't know exactly, if data is transfering to server and then to client, or server just "tells" clients about each other and they publish through p2p then. Btw, Is it really important for you?

Comment: well yes if its not p2p then the bandwidth cost of live video (1 to 1) will be insane